# Как ограничить источник запроса к php скрипту?

Tags: php

Я не программист и мои знания заканчиваются на отметке "поправить или дописать написанное" в коде. Но недавно, возникла ситуация где мне пришлось работать с php (с js никак). Так вот, есть приложение, которое через ajax, делает запрос с пометкой "to" к скрипту находящемуся на том же сервере где и само приложение. Объясню: суть скрипта "отнеси-отдай" для mysq, к примеру id vk. Так вот, появилась проблема, когда любой сможет создать запрос (если узнает путь, название и название запроса), а также изменяь данные пользователей, подставляя в переменные любой id vk (аккаунты пользователей привязаны к нему) и делать, что угодно, менять даннве и получать их. Конечно, вероятность слива такой информации мала, но все же, хочется быть уверенным, среда разработки не позволяет в полной мере работать с кодом, только запросы. Так вот, сам впорос. Можно ли ограничить источник подключения к скрипту? Приложения и скрипт, находятся на одном домене/сервере. В смысле,чтобы к скрипту могли подключаться только локальные соединения. Спасибо за внимание и заранее спасибо!

Comment: Генерируйте число для страницы и добавляйте его в cookie и в Ajax запрос. Этим вы обезопасите себя от запросов вне сессии. Посмотрите любой скрипт авторизации через Ajax. Там присутствует уникальный ID формы.

Comment: Не очень понял суть. Но я сделал одноразовую генерацию уникального ключа (не знаю зачем) для сессии пользователя, в принципе этот ключ можно сунуть в запрос ajax, только скрипт что с ним будет делать? Он вроде бы как постоянно обновляется при каждой новой сессии. Вообще я думал, что скажут как нибудь через .htacess запретить внешние подключения.

Comment: Кстати, ключ после создания в клиенте приложения, я сразу отправляю в базу данных (через тот же ajax запрос), думал попытаться что-то написать на пыхе "аля проверка ключика", но потом посмотрел на чистый документ, на себя, на свои руки, еще раз на себя и заплакал как маленькая девочка. До сих пор бешусь с того, что выучился на несчастного экономиста, вместо полезного направления.

Comment: Если у вас приложение именно ВКонтакте (внутри, IFrame), то проверять кто отправил запрос можно через [auth_key](https://vk.com/dev/apps_init?f=3.%20auth_key)

Comment: добавьте в скрипт Basic Auth, например.

Comment: Возможно BA и помогает, по крайней мере в документации по нему, написано про страницы, а мне нужно организовать защиту соединения по ajax. С вк api, уже сталкивались, для того чтобы этот api начал с нами работать, нужно создавать плагин для нашей среды разработки. Это ужасно, поэтому мы сразу откинули эту затею прочь. Вернусь к BA. ни один ресурс подробно не написал, как встроить эту авторизацию в свой скрипт, скорее бывалому программисту будет понятно. Но никак не коллективу из 3 дизайнеров и 1 логиста. Впрочем, пока тема актуальна, мы ожидали более легких путей решения этого вопроса :c